# matplotlib savefig doesn't work when run with crontab

Tags: python, matplotlib, cron

I'm trying to run a python script with crontab that uses matplotlib to save a plot png. The script runs fine when run normally/not by cron.

My crontab file is:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
* * * * * /home/matthew/Programs/random_walk/random_walk.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Permissions seem to be set correctly and pythonpath seems right; I added a couple lines to `random_walk.py` that write a file with the `sys.path` output, and that worked when run by cron.

Several blog posts and mailing lists suggested the problem would be resolved by having

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

at the top of my python file (after the shebang), but that doesn't help.

My `savefig` code is

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    save_path = sys.argv[1].rstrip('/')+'/random_walk.png'
else:
    save_path = 'random_walk.png'
plt.savefig(save_path)
```

How can I get cron and matplotlib to play nicely together?

Comment: Have you tried to dump your script output into a file and see if it's throwing any error?

Comment: do you set PYTHONPATH anywhere?  Remember that crontab runs with a very limited enviroment

Comment: @jabaldonedo There were no errors in the script output. @tcaswell PYTHONPATH seems to be set correctly because when I tell the script to output `sys.path`, it works.

Comment: I'm not experienced with crontab, so I expect I've messed that up in some way.

Comment: It is output correctly when the script is run from the terminal or by cron?  How are you using `savefig`?  I could see relative paths not playing nice.  You need to provide more information, as it stands this question is basically un-answerable.

Comment: @tcaswell Ah I feel like and idiot now. It was a paths issue. I had set up the python script to plot to a directory based on command line input but the crontab wasn't passing in the right path. I'll accept if you answer.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what the problem was, you should answer your own question.  Now that you have solved your problem, I have flagged this as too localized as the real problem is in code you do not show in the question.

Comment: @tcaswell I'll add the code to the question. I didn't want to delete the question because it is the only search result for "crontab matplotlib."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @tcaswell, I figured out that the problem was a paths issue.

My crontab file was not passing the image file location to random_walk.py, so the image was being saved in the same directory as my crontab file- not the same directory as random_walk.py where I was expecting it.

### Solution 1

Pass the path to the script in crontab like I meant to.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
* * * * * /home/matthew/Programs/random_walk/random_walk.py /home/matthew/Programs/random_walk >/dev/null 2>&1
```

### Solution 2

Alternatively, I could just make the python script always write its output file where I want it to go. In this case, I want the output file to be in the same directory as the random_walk.py, so I'm using the following code:

```
save_path = ''
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    save_path = sys.argv[1].rstrip('/')+'/random_walk.png'
else:
    save_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/random_walk.png'
plt.savefig(save_path)
```

### Note

Just to be clear, having

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

was also necessary to get matplotlib to work with cron.

Comment: What is the wait time?  I should really know this given by habit of pestering people about this....

Comment: @tcaswell It says 14 hours left, but I thought the wait time was 2 days though, so that doesn't make sense. I quickly searched meta but didn't find the answer.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but in my case my python script stops running when plt.plot is called. It throws an exception for an Invalid DISPLAY variable. So I had to export DISPLAY=:0 in my python script.